# HDD Abnormalities

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, smart, file-corruption

I am pretty sure that my HDD is broken, but tests after show that it is mostly fine.  About 1 month ago, my HDD clicked about 10 times on Windows 10 boot, this corrupted the boot sector of every operating system that I had on my disk.  Windows 10 was no longer viewed as a valid operating system, only booted into BSOD. Ubuntu loads grub, and then freezes half way through loading the kernel. And practically every other OS that I have on my disk does these two things now. The HDD has never clicked before this, and never has clicked since.

The Hard Disk is 4 years old, as well as the system it is running on. There was 0 indication other than the corruption, that there is anything wrong with the disk. The system is a Toshiba Satellite S50-A.

**But my big question** is if this is a problem with my Motherboard, a problem with the cabling/connection, a problem with the HDD, or just a once off issue. Because I went out and bought a new 500GB Samsung SSD, and I need to know if I can put it in my system, without it damaging the drive (due to possible motherboard/connection issues).

I have done disk benchmarks via, pulling the information off of the disk after the Operating Systems became corrupt, and by doing multiple Ubuntu Disks Benchmarks.  The ~600GB of files transfered in a time of ~9 days, to a brand new 1TB USB3.0 HDD backup drive (Seagate Backup Plus Portable Drive SRD00F1).  The External Drive was definitely not the issue. And all of the Files, except for specific folders in the Windows Folder and the boot sectors of the Operating Systems, were NOT corrupted.

**Day 4**
[image: Day 4]

**Day 8**
[image: Day 8,Lots of I/O Error Files that did not copy (mostly those in the the Windows Folder)]

And the Synthetic Disk Benchmarks:

**Smallest File Read/Write Test, and Latency Test (NTFS)**
[image: Smallest File Read/Write Test, and Latency Test (NTFS)]

**Smallest File Read/Write Test (NTFS)**
[image: Smallest File Read/Write Test (NTFS)]

**2x Larger Smallest File Read/Write Test (NTFS)**
[image: 2x Larger Smallest File Read/Write Test (NTFS)]

**Smallest File Read/Write Test Alternate Partition (EXT4)**
[image: Smallest File Read/Write Test Alternate Partition (EXT4)]

**Medium File Read/Write Test (EXT4)**
[image: Medium File Read/Write Test (EXT4)]

**Largest File Read/Write Test (EXT4)**
[image: Largest File Read/Write Test (EXT4)]

So I recently ran a Full SMART test on the disk

---

```
root@ubuntu:~# smartctl -a -d ata /dev/sda
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.13.0-21-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABD...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABD075
Serial Number:    53FDW2NFT
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 4c4a8512d
Firmware Version: AX0A4M
User Capacity:    750,156,374,016 bytes [750 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat Feb 17 03:43:40 2018 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 189) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       2393
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4214
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   082   082   000    Old_age   Always       -       7262
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   182   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3514
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2875
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       186
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       86269
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 14/61)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   085   085   000    Old_age   Always       -       6297
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       262
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      7261         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7258         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2743         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2731         -
# 5  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      2731         -
# 6  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      90%      2730         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2730         -
# 8  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      2730         -
# 9  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      2730         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2727         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2727         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

100% bad sectors of the HDD. Test the surface (verify) of the HDDScan program (http://hddscan.com/) under liveCD Windows or the Victoria program from under DOS. Under the replacement.

Comment: How can there be 100% bad sectors if less than 10% of the disk was corrupted?

Comment: @user8079 I think "100%" here may mean "bad sectors are the issue *for sure*". In my opinion the answer is far from being clear.

Comment: What is not clear to you here? only checking the surface on bad sectors from the program to liveCD in the modes of "verify" first, and then "erase", then again "verify" can show how corrupted the hard disk is. Yes, and clicks.

Comment: "What is not clear to you here?" – "100%"; you still haven't clarified whether it's "100% of sectors are bad" or "there's a 100% chance some sectors are bad" or something else. And what does this part refer to: "Under the replacement"?

Comment: What "this part"? If the hard disk clicks while trying to position the heads, then the tests are only needed to determine the degree of damage. In any case - the disk for replacement